# Postgres bulk insert into different schemas

Tags: postgresql

We currently store things into Redis for temporary aggregation and have a worker that goes and does insertion in bulk into Postgres. Is there a way that we can do bulk insert across multiple schemas in a single Insert transaction? This will remove the need to aggregate things in Redis. Or, is there a better way to aggregate the requests?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I suppose you could set up a table with an INSERT trigger and have your trigger function's logic figure out which table to write to, and then just COPY into that table. Not something I've tried before or benchmarked, but my expectation is that this would be slower than just having one insert per target table.

Comment: What is a "single Insert transaction" supposed to be? Single transaction - sure, no problem. Single INSERT - basically not possible, INSERT inserts into a *single* table. Workaround with rules or triggers or partitioning possible ... Please present a proper question with details.

Comment: I would suggest a different approach. Make Postgres access Redis resources as foreign tables by using redis_fdw (https://pgxn.org/dist/redis_fdw/). Schedule a Postgres SQL job that queries Redis tables and  inserts into Postgres schemata/tables. You can do it in a single transaction as an anonymous PL/pgSQL `do` block.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean with "single insert transaction".

One single `INSERT` statement can only affect one specific table. However you could still `BEGIN` a transaction (depends on implementation), perform all of your `INSERT` in there and then `COMMIT` the transaction.
This would still be more efficient than performing all the `INSERT`s on many transactions since it avoid redundant "hand shakings".

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating an update-able view that references two tables and then bulk insert in to this view?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
with data (c1, c2) as (
  values (1,2),(10,20),(30,40)
), s1_insert as (
  insert into schema_one.table_1(c1, c2)
  select c1, c2
  from data
)
insert into schema_two.table_2(col1, col2)
select c1, c2
from data;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you execute a insert statement a single transaction will happen and you can only insert in a single table(So inserting across multiple schema is altogether not possible *in a single transaction*).

Comment: That should be "*not possible in a single **statement***" - it's absolutely possible to have one transaction that inserts into tables in different schemas.